# How to Index Only Pages with Certain Urls with Nutch?

Tags: indexing, nutch, restrict, url

I want nutch to crawl abc.com, but  I want to index only car.abc.com.  car.abc.com links can in any levels in abc.com.  So, basically, I want nutch to keep crawl abc.com normally, but index only pages that start as car.abc.com.  e.g. car.abc.com/toyota...car.abc.com/honda...

I set the regex-urlfilter.txt to include only car.abc.com and run the command "generate crawl/crawldb crawl/segments", but it just say "Generator: 0 records selected for fetching, exiting ..." .  I guess car.abc.com links exist only in several levels deep.

How to do this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the -filter switch of the mergedb command. The command takes a crawl db as input and created a new crawl db with some urls filtered. Just use that filtered crawl db for indexing.

The only drawback to this is that I have not found a way for the mergedb command to use another file than regex-urlfilter.txt, which is the file used by the generator. You will have to maintain two files like regex-urlfilter.txt: one used for the generator with *abc.com* and another one used for the mergedb command that excludes urls not like *car.abc.com*. But since both command try to load the same file, you will have to rename the appropriate file to regex-urlfilter.txt before calling one of the two commands.

If someone knows a way to configure the mergedb command to use another file, I'd be happy to hear it!