# How to crawl specific pages with nutch 2.3?

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch

I am new to nutch. After serveral hours of searching I couldn't figure out how to choose the right settings for my crawler.

First of all I have installed nutch 2.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 using hbase 0.94.14 and elasticsearch 1.4.2.

I started using nutch running the following commands in nutch's runtime/local directory:

```
bin/nutch inject seedfolder
bin/nutch generate -topN 20
bin/nutch fetch -all
bin/nutch parse -all
bin/nutch updatedb -all
bin/nutch index -all
```

I can then access the crawled data via elasticsearch. So everything seems to work nicely.

My problem starts when I want to bring nutch to only crawl the sites I am interested in. I read lots of tutorials including the ones I found on the apache web site. One thing that really confuses me is the big difference between the versions of nutch. But also some of the questions I have never have been asked or answered.

What I want to do:
I want to tell nutch what page to crawl (of course it will be more that one but let's keep it simple). I do that by adding an url to my seed file and calling nutch inject. Now let's say I want to crawl http://www.pagetocrawl.com/intresting-facts more precisely I am interested in the contents of

```
http://www.pagetocrawl.com/intresting-facts?interesting-fact-id=1 
http://www.pagetocrawl.com/intresting-facts?interesting-fact-id=2
http://www.pagetocrawl.com/intresting-facts?interesting-fact-id=3 
...
```

What I thought was the necessary thing to do was editing NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local/conf/regex-urlfilter.xml and adding something like

```
+http://www.pagetocrawl.com/intresting-facts
```

When I tried to run the generate and fetch command I noticed that in fact nutch only crawled sites starting with pagetocrawl.com and didn't touch the other sites I had injected earlier. But then it crawled all the pages that

```
http://www.pagetocrawl.com/interesting-facts
```

linked to. That is the imprint, where-to-find-us page etc. In the end it didn't crawl even one sigle interesting-fact site. So my two most imporant questions are: How can I tell nutch to crawl only that subsites of my sites filtered by regex-urlfilter.xml that do also match a specific pattern? And in the next step: How can I be sure to crawl all of the relevant subsites (as long as thy are linked to from http://www.pagetocrawl.com/interesting-facts site)?

I've looked at

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/19731904/exclude-urls-without-www-from-nutch-1-7-crawl
```

but here the problem seems to appear one step earlier I added my url to regex-urlfilter.xml and it seems to be working - just not the way I expected it to work.

I've also read that question:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/3253525/how-to-index-only-pages-with-certain-urls-with-nutch
```

This seems to describe the very same problem I have. But since I am working with nutch 2.3 the mergedb command doesn't seem to work any longer.

I do really hope I described my problem propery and that somebody can help me with that.

Comment: Did you try this :  +^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*pagetocrawl.com/intresting-facts

Comment: Hi Computergodzilla! I am not sure how this might help me.  I think, the part of the URL before `interesting-facts` works fine. I'm just not sure how to set the filter for the part that comes after that. Anyway I tried it but then the generator job produces a timeout exception.

Comment: Please take a look at **(Optional) Configure Regular Expression Filters** section in [Nutch Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial). It says that it will crawl all the site of only pagetocrawl.com domain.

Comment: Thank you. By now I figured out that I missunderstood my own problem. I tried to crawl another site that worked like
    anotherpagetocrawl.com/interesting-facts/interesting-fact1.html 
    anotherpagetocrawl.com/interesting-facts/interesting-fact2.html 
I didn't have any problems here with crawling only the relevant pages and die settings in regex-urlfilter.txt do really work the way I expected them to work.
So my problem is really how to bring nutch to not ignore the parameters interesting-fact-id which it is currently doing. But that gives me a new persepective for searching for solutions.